# 2 different lines of code don't work at first time, then work

Tags: c

My code should generate 5 arrays.

- 1st and 2nd with arguments from 0 to maximal resolution of window (graphics generate window ( width, height ))
- 3rd and 4th with arguments from -20 to 20
- 5th with arguments which are equal to power from number of ball + 1

However, on VisualStudio 2k8 and 2k12, the 1st array is full of 0, 3rd have values far greater than (-)20 and 5th have even numbers smaller than 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "winbgi2.h"

int s, w;
int i;
int x[20], y[20], vx[20], vy[20], m[20]; 

void init(int a[20], int b[20], int c[20], int d[20], int e[20]);

void main() {
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

    int min;
    int max;
    min = 100;
    max = 1000;
    s = min + rand() % max;
    w = min + rand() % max;

    graphics(s, w);

    init(&x[20], &y[20], &vx[20], &vy[20], &m[20]);

    for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        printf("Array element x=%ld \t is equal to %ld\n", i, x[i]);
    };

    for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        printf("Array element y=%ld \t is equal to %ld\n", i, y[i]);
    };

    for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        printf("Array element vx=%ld \t is equal to %ld\n", i, vx[i]);
    };

    for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        printf("Array element vy=%ld \t is equal to %ld\n", i, vy[i]);
    };

    for (i = 1;i <= 20; i++) {
        printf("Mass of ball m=%ld \tis %ld\n", i, m[i]);
    };

    wait();
}

void init(int a[20], int b[20], int c[20], int d[20], int e[20]) {
    for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
        a[i] = rand() % s;

    for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
        b[i] = rand() % w;

    for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
        c[i] =- 20 + rand() % 40;

    for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
        d[i] =- 20 + rand() % 40;

    for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
        e[i] = i * i * 2 + 1;
}
```

Im feeling dazed: why this code one time works bad, and next time everything is good.

Comment: Do something about the formatting of the code. Also arrays in C are indexed from zero onwards

Comment: This looks awful. In addition it is `int main (void) { return 0; }` or `int main (int argc, char *argv[]) { return 0; }` in C.

Comment: The sequence is 0 origin  in C.

Comment: You're passing the wrong things in your call to the `init` function. Passing `&x[20]` passes an address of one element beyond the `x` array, which doesn't exist and therefore causes undefined behavior. What you meant to do is simply `init(x, y, vx, vy, m)`. Adding the address-of operator `&` and the subscript `[20]` makes it completely wrong.

Comment: You have lots of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Your code does not make any sense. You should enable all warnings & debug info, and use the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- Index values are `0` based in C. Valid index values for your arrays of 20 elements are 0 to 19.  Your loops should be written:

  ```
  for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
      a[i] = rand() % s;
  ```
- The call to `init` should read:

  ```
  init(x, y, vx, vy, m);
  ```
- You should not define the variables at the global scope, make them local variables in the body of the `main` function and define `i` in the body of the `init` function too.
- `=-` is not an operator, the statement `c[i] =- 20 + rand() % 40;` in parsed as `c[i] = -20 + (rand() % 40);` which is probably your intent, but your presentation is misleading. Use this instead:

  ```
  c[i] = -20 + rand() % 40;
  ```
- The `;` after the `}` at the end of the body of the `for` statements are useless and should be removed.

As currently written, the code invokes undefined behavior in many places, which means anything can happen.